# Use click event of MorrisJs with Angular 6

Tags: angular, onclick, click, morris.js

I use [this wrapper of MorrisJs Chart](https://github.com/mika-el/angular-morris-js) in one project. This works very well, but I cannot find a way to get the result of click event.

With the original Morris.js using jQuery, it is possible to get the click event like this:

```
Morris.Line({ 
    ...
}).on('click', function(i, row) { 
    console.log(i);
    console.log(row);
});
```

Do you know how to intercept that click with Angular? Thanks!

Comment: Is this not working for you? Would it be possible to create a [Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating your issue?

Comment: if you can avoid usign morrisjs do it. I love morrisJs but it's not good practice to use jQuery in angular apps. MorrisJS depends on jQuery

Comment: @PatricioVargas Actually I love MorrisJS, that is the less verbose chart library and it matches perfectly with Angular when number of charts is dynamic, thus I eventually made a fork which is jQuery-free, and it works perfectly, the only missing point is that click event :) https://pierresh.github.io/morris.js/

Comment: coooool! i went to their npm and it says jQuery dependency. Thanks, I just learned something new. Time to go back to morrisJS :)

Comment: For that maybe interested with the solution, I just published below the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the solution. 3 changes should be brought to the directive:

1. `import Output, EventEmitter`
2. initialize the output to be an event emitter `@Output() clickChart = new
   EventEmitter();`
3. Bind the Morris chart click event with the directive output: 
   `let my_this = this;
   this.chartInstance.on('click', function(i, row) { 
       my_this.clickChart.emit({ event, i, row });
   });`

Then the click event can be caught in the component through the method `(clickChart)`.
Example:

```
<div    mk-morris-js
        type='Bar'
        [options]='options'
        [data]='datas'
        (clickChart)='test($event)'
></div>
```

The full source of the directive can be seen in [my pull request](https://github.com/mika-el/angular-morris-js/pull/9/files).

Comment: Can you provide me an example of how this is achieved? I already have a working chart on my end. I am using the latest version of the library and it seems that your changes are merged. However, the function is never called when I click on the chart.

Comment: Nevermind, I downloaded the source code, applied the modifications on the demo project, and is working there. Must be a configuration issue on my end. Thanks for the changes :)